# Divide column by 1000 if maximum exceed certain limit

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, apply

I want to code very simple program: It should go through all columns in data frame and if there is at least one observation bigger than 1000 then program should divide this variable by 1000 and add `"in (000)"` to the variable name.

**My solution**

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame("Norm" = rnorm(100, 1000, 0.1), rexp(100))

for (var in seq_len(ncol(df))) {
  if (max(df[, var], na.rm = T) > 1000) {
    df[, var] <- df[, var] / 1000
    colnames(df)[var] <- print(paste(colnames(df[var]), "(in 000')"))
  }
}
```

However I find it little inconvenient. I think that loop is not necessary here. I tried to do it with apply, but I'm not sure why I obtain maximum of column divided by 1000 instead of data frame in which each value is divided by 1000:

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) ifelse(max(x) > 1000, x/1000, x))

 Norm rexp.100. 
0.9999925 0.4473922
```

Do you know how it can be done without loops ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` is for matrices, don't use it on data frames. And `ifelse` is for vector tests - the output is the same shape as the input. Your input to `ifelse()` is `max(x) > 1000` which has length 1, so the result will be length 1. You could use `lapply` instead of `for` and `if(){}else{}` instead of `ifelse()`:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) if(max(x, na.rm = TRUE) > 1000) {x / 1000}else{x})
```

But with *apply family functions you have to go back and change the name in another step---I often prefer `for` in a case like that.

But I would probably do it this way without looping:

```
cols_over_1000 = sapply(df, max, na.rm = TRUE) > 1000
df[cols_over_1000] = df[cols_over_1000] / 1000
names(df)[cols_over_1000] = paste(names(df)[cols_over_1000], "(in '000)")
```

Or in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(
    where(~ any(. > 1000)),
    ~ . / 1000,
    .names = "{.col} (in '000)"
  ))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ab1k <- sapply(df, function(x) any(x > 1000))
df[ab1k] <- df[ab1k]/1000
names(df)[ab1k] <- paste(names(df)[ab1k], "(in 000')")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with `purrr` package like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

my_fun <- function(x,y){
      if(max(x, na.rm = T)>1000){
            return(rename_with(tibble(x/1000),~paste0(y,"(in '000)")))
      }else{return(rename_with(tibble(x),~y))}
}

map2_dfc(df,names(df),my_fun)
```